# How can I use the Gitlab CDN adapter with the Azure Standard CDN, which does not offer ETag

Tags: gitlab, microsoft-cdn

Gitlab's [external storage for static objects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/static_objects_external_storage.html) has the potential to speed up an instance substantially and off-load a lot of work. I have access to the [Azure CDN Standard Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-features) product, but not the more expensive versions.

The [Protocol definition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/static_objects_external_storage.html#requests-flow-example) requires an ETag return value. My problem is that:

> [Azure CDN Standard/Premium from Verizon **supports ETag** by default, while **Azure CDN Standard from Microsoft** and Azure CDN Standard from Akamai do **not**.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works#validators)

Does anyone know if the Gitlab CDN adapter can be implemented without ETag? If so, how?